# How to render children in react component without passing it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have component:

```js
const PapeConainer = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div //some classes and other stuff>
     {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

But on merge request got a comment that i don't need to pass children, because function already has it. So, my questing is it possible to render children without passing it. I`m not found any information on this.

like:

```js
const PapeConainer = () => {
  return (
    <div //some classes and other stuff>
     {magic.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: children always need to be passed if you think about it, but probably they are referring to declaring them as input props? if you are using arrow functions you always should declare it as input because arrow functions don't have `this` context, so there's no other way to do it, the first code block you showed is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can't do that, you have to get the children object from props, just as you said:

```
const PapeContainer = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div //some classes and other stuff>
     {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I think that what that comment wanted to say is that you don't have to pass children as a specific prop named "children" in your parent component, like this:

```
<PapeContainer //some classes and other stuff
   children={someChildren}
/>
```

That would not make sense because "children" is a special property of React which contains any child elements defined within the component. So instead of passing the prop explicitly you put the children content inside the parent tag.

So the **correct way** would be like this:

```
<PapeContainer /* other properties here */>
   {someChildren}
</PageContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can not do that. What you are able to do is to pass the children as a component prop or as an hierarchy children, like this (which is the same component prop, but with another code implementation):

```
// The children container component
function ReceiveChild({children}) {
    return (
        {children}
    );
}

// DOM Element hierarchy method component
function PassChild() {
    return (
        <ReceiveChild>
            <p className="the-child-div">Children</p>
        </ReceiveChild>
    );
}

// Component prop method component
function PassChild2() {
    return (
        <ReceiveChild children={
            <p className="the-child-div">
                Children
            </p>} 
        />
    );
}
```