# How to create React element using React.createElement with child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to create element using React Component with child.

Here's my React Component:

```
const Element = () => {
    return (
        <div class='element'>/* child should be here*/</div>
    );
}

export default Element;
```

and here's how I want to do it:

```
React.createElement(Element, {}, [
    React.createElement('span', { className: 'text' }, 'text 1'),
    React.createElement('span', { className: 'text' }, 'text 2')
])
```

output should be:

```
<div class="element">
    <span class="text">text 1</span>
    <span class="text">text 2</span>
</div>
```

Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: The `Element` component is not rendering its children. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65674663/how-to-render-children-in-react-component-without-passing-it this should help)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a prop named `children` which contains the children in the component

so you can use

```js
const Element = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className='element'>{children}</div>
  );
}

export default Element;
```

and the html property `class` should be `className` in react.